# Select row from one table where multiple rows in another table have determined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL: 
Products:

```
  id  |  value
================
   1  |   foo
   2  |   bar   
   3  |   foobar
   4  |   barbar
```

And properties:

```
  product_id  |  property_id
=============================
       1      |       10
       1      |       11
       2      |       15     
       2      |       16
       3      |       10    
       3      |       11
       4      |       10
       4      |       16
```

I want to get products that have determined properties. 
For example I need to get all products that have properties with ids 10 and 11. And I expect   products with ids 1 and 3 but not 4!

Is it possible in mysql or I need to use PHP for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I believe it is possible in MySQL. You will not have to go for a PHP solution.

Comment: `select * from properties where property_id in ('10', '11')` In your case, you may want to use parameters for inputting the properties to prevent injection.

Comment: Why "propety_id" and not "property_id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with ids 10 and 11

Here's 2 solutions:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.value, 
       Count(DISTINCT propety_id) 
FROM   products p 
       INNER JOIN properties pr 
               ON p.id = pr.product_id 
                  AND propety_id IN ( 10, 11 ) 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT propety_id) = 2;
```

or....

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.value 
FROM   products p 
       INNER JOIN properties pr1 
               ON p.id = pr2.product_id 
                  AND pr1.propety_id = 10 
       INNER JOIN properties pr2 
               ON p.id = pr2.product_id 
                  AND pr2.propety_id = 11;
```

As for excluding rows - add a NOT exists clause, or do an additional left join and exclude matching rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [products] 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT product_id 
              FROM   [properties] 
              WHERE  propety_id IN ( '10', '11' ) 
              HAVING Count(DISTINCT propety_id) = 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM   product p 
       INNER JOIN properties prop 
               ON p.id = prop.product_id 
                  AND property_id IN ( 10, 11 ) 
GROUP  BY p.id 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT property_id) = 2
```

Comment: "HAVING SUM(property_id) = 2" - but 10 + 11 = 21?

Comment: @symcbean yes count it is.

Comment: Without distinct in count you can get id with(10,10) or (11,11)

Comment: I suppose if you wer particularly masochistic you could try to solve the problem using a variant of a Golomb ruler.

Comment: @symcbean Could you try?You made me curious.

Comment: Using SUM() - but you need a set property ids (say P) where P[a] + P[b] does not exist in the set P. e.g. 1,2,5,9,13 - although you also need to cater for the possibility that a value might appear more than one in the output of the query pre-aggregation.

Comment: There are better examples of Golomb rulers on the wikipedia page.

Comment: (but it's only of academic interest since it precludes the use of an index to resolve the query on a relational database)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+--------+
| id | value  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | foo    |
|  2 | bar    |
|  3 | foobar |
|  4 | barbar |
+----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM properties;
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | property_id |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          10 |
|          1 |          11 |
|          2 |          15 |
|          2 |          16 |
|          3 |          10 |
|          3 |          11 |
|          4 |          10 |
|          4 |          16 |
+------------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now we select all the product ids, that have property_ids IN (10, 11) and having 2 distinct rows for property_id:

```
mysql> SELECT
        product_id FROM properties 
WHERE
        properties.property_id IN (10, 11) 
GROUP BY
      product_id 
HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT property_id) = 2;

+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          3 |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Combining this query with SELECT-ing from products:

```
mysql> SELECT
        id, value
FROM
        products
WHERE
        products.id IN(
SELECT
        product_id FROM properties 
WHERE
        properties.property_id IN (10, 11) 
GROUP BY
      product_id 
HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT property_id) = 2);

+----+--------+
| id | value  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | foo    |
|  3 | foobar |
+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9784/1)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but this solution is extremely slow. In my database it works 0.2569 seconds.

Comment: second solution in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20760903/1930582) works trice faster

Comment: @wshakura I couldn't know it, as I was testing on a small dataset, and it gave 0 seconds for me. The best solution must be checkmarked of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT Prd.*
FROM products As Prd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id ,SUM(RStatus) As Tt
            FROM (SELECT product_id,
                CASE 
                    WHEN propety_id = 10 THEN NULL
                    WHEN propety_id = 11 THEN NULL
                    ELSE 0
                END  As RStatus
            FROM properties 
                  ) A
        GROUP BY product_id
        ) AS Prt ON(Prd.ID = Prt.product_id )
WHERE Prt.Tt IS  NULL
```