# Select row from one table where multiple rows in another table may have determined values, the number of conditions varies

Tags: sql, mysql

The situation is quite similar to that shown in this question [Select row from one table where multiple rows in another table have determined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760813/select-row-from-one-table-where-multiple-rows-in-another-table-have-determined-v), but the condition is more complex.

I have two tables in MySQL:

Products:

```
  id  |  value
================
   1  |   foo
   2  |   bar   
   3  |   foobar
   4  |   barbar
   5  |   five
   6  |   six
```

And properties:

```
  product_id  |  property_id
=============================
       1      |       10
       1      |       11
       2      |       15     
       2      |       16
       3      |       10    
       3      |       11
       3      |       12
       4      |       10
       4      |       16
       5      |       16
       6      |       11
```

I may have a filter that defines various number of properties to be selected, let's say I am interested in 3 of them. So I need to choose products and order them according to the following conditions:

1. at first products having all 3 properties,
2. then products having 2 properties only (if not matched by the first condition)
3. then products having only 1 property (if not matched by conditions 1 and 2)

Within each condition the items are ordered according to property_id in ascending order.

So if I want to pick products with property_id = 10 or property_id = 11 or property_id = 12, then my results should be the following:

1. product_id=3 (it has properties 10, 11 and 12)
2. product_id=1 (it has properties 10 and 11)
3. product_id=4 (it has property 10)
4. product_id=6 (it has property 11)

How this can be efficiently done by MySQL?

Comment: huh? can't you reuse the linked solution add `order by` clause `desc` on the `count` and the `having` clause checks for `>1` instead of equality check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order` the `count` directly or lazily wrap it in another `select` as the `from` reference.

```
SELECT p.id ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT property_id) as matches
FROM   products as p 
       INNER JOIN properties as prop 
             ON p.id = prop.product_id 
                AND property_id IN (10, 11)
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property_id) >= 1
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

The query will return:

| id | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

Keep in mind product with `id` 6 won't appear as it doesn't exists in the `products` table.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1iZeMRQo95KvVLcZrFedd/2

It might be better for readability by using CTE, but I digress..

Comment: "Given that ordering the count result is not possible in the same query" - untrue.  you can take your subquery as is and just add `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT property_id) desc, p.id`. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g1iZeMRQo95KvVLcZrFedd/1

Comment: @ysth oh right, my bad. i posted it without thinking much. why don't you add it as an answer? i think it would perform better.

Comment: Bagus and @ysth, thank you both for the input. Both solutions work perfectly for my case. Thank you also for pointing out that product id=6 was missing, that was a mistake in my initial data, it was assumed to be there.

Comment: @BagusTesa you went to the trouble of making a fiddle, you can just change your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select product_id,sum(case property_id when 10 then 1 when 11 then 1 when 12 then 1 else 0 end) as hits 
from  properties 
group by product_id
having hits >=1
order by hits desc
;

-- result set:
+------------+------+
| product_id | hits |
+------------+------+
|          3 |    3 |
|          1 |    2 |
|          4 |    1 |
|          6 |    1 |
+------------+------+
```

Note: This is assuming the `properties` table does not have duplicate rows. If it does,we will need to use the derived table `(select distinct * from properties) as tb` instead of base table for the FROM clause.